How to respect filter in the feedback path in the controller design phase?
Let's say I have unity feedback control loop

here the closed loop transfer function will be
$$ C_1 = \frac{D\cdot G}{1 + D\cdot G} $$
then I have feedback control loop with a filter in
the feedback path

here the closed loop transfer function will be
$$ C_2 = \frac{D\cdot G}{1 + H\cdot D\cdot G} $$
i.e. the closed loop transfer functions are different but the open loop
transfer functions are the same for both cases.
My question is how I can include the filter in the feedback path into the design phase of the controller because the design methods (root-locus, frequency domain) are based on the open loop transfer function? Thanks in advance for explanation.

For those methods you mention the openloop actually refers to the transfer function one obtains when "cutting" open the closed loop transfer function at the negative feedback summation, as shown here:

So the openloop transfer function $L(s)$ one would obtain in this case is
$$
L(s) = H(s)\,G(s)\,D(s).
$$
